# change this js code from inline to external

Tags: javascript

After looking up good practices on inline vs external javascript it seems external is always best, so i have this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('textarea').sceditor({
    charset: 'UTF-8',
    plugins: 'bbcode',
    width: "100%",
    autoExpand: true,
    toolbar: "bold,italic,underline,strike,quote|bulletlist|left,center,right|link,unlink|youtube,emoticon,image|pastetext|removeformat|maximize|source",
    style: "/includes/jscripts/sce/jquery.sceditor.default.min.css",
    enablePasteFiltering: true,
    // Emoticons list
    emoticons: {
    dropdown: {
    ":><:": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/angry.png",
    ":'(": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/cry.png",
    ":dizzy:": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/dizzy.png",
    ":D": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/grin.png",
    "^_^": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/happy.png",
    "<3": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/heart.png",
    ":huh:": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/huh.png",
    ":|": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/pouty.png",
    ":(": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/sad.png",
    ":O": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/shocked.png",
    ":sick:": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/sick.png",
    ":)": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/smile.png",
    ":P": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/tongue.png",
    ":S:": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/unsure.png",
    ":woot:": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/w00t.png",
    ":whistle:": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/whistle.png",
    ";)": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/wink.png",
    ":wub:": "/includes/jscripts/sce/emoticons/wub.png"
        }}
        }).change(function(e){
            var $this = $(this),
                $preview = $this.siblings('#preview');

        });
});
```

How can I make it so that works correctly when in an externally included file? It's code used with [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com).

Comment: Load jQuery, then the plugin, and then the external file with your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy this content to a file like myjs.js and include the file in you page using

```
<script src="myjs.js"></script>
```

Since it is using jQuery, this file inclusion should happen after jQuery is inlcuded

Comment: @Liam Dawe can you share what other script files are included and the order

Comment: @LiamDawe also check whether there is any error in the console